# Want to display CGridview based on a field in table and distinguish them in display?

Tags: php, css, yii

> I have CGridview which consists of list of messages, I want to distinguish it by read and unread by color change in grid, I am not good in CSS so I don' t have any Idea about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add in main.css

   ```
   .grid-view table.items tr.unread {
       background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FF0000 !important; /* red color is unread */
    }

   .grid-view table.items tr.read {
       background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #00FF00 !important; /* green color is read */
   }
   ```
2. In model of message

   ```
   function isRead()
   {
       return $this->hasRead;
   }
   ```
3. In CGridView add row css class expression

   ```
   'rowCssClassExpression' => '$data->isRead()?"read":"unread"',
   ```

Comment: Just added some code highlighting, when we write code within lists, you need 8 spaces instead of the usual 4 :)